# Bank Statement To Get Schengen visa

Tags: visa

I am going to study at university in Hungary. But I have one problem: my bank statement is not sufficient. A company or person in my hometown is going to be responsible for my tuition fees and everything in Hungary. So is it possible to be get a visa?

Comment: Are you asking if it is acceptable to have a sponsor cover your financial costs, or what the chances are of a successful application with a sponsor (or both)? The latter question is pretty much impossible to answer.

Comment: First Question please i have sponsor to cover my financial cost in my hometown but not close relatives